# Путь до папки с доменом

Tags: php, пути

В $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] есть путь "/var/www/mydomin/data/www/mydomin.ru", мне надо обрезать его и получить "/var/www/mydomin/data/www/"

Answer (score 1):

```
$domain = "/var/www/mydomin/data/www/mydomin.ru";

$parts = explode('/', $domain);
$count = count($parts);
unset($parts[$count - 1]);

$final_string = join('/', $parts);
echo $final_string;
```